# npm '[...] ' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

Recently got this error message every time I type in npm into cmd.

```
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

npm still seems to work but I get a lot of errors when trying to install electron and I thought it might be related.

I've already completely reinstalled node.js and npm twice...
Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add this variable path `;C:\Program Files\nodejs\` to the variable **PATH** on the **User variable** section of the Environment Variables and normally it should work when you type again `npm`.

Comment: Can you show me your Variable **ComSpec** from **Environment Variables** ?

Comment: Sure %USERPROFILE%\platform-tools_r28.0.1-windows\platform-tools

Comment: Your **ComSpec** should only containt that variable (%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe)

Comment: still no difference, guess I have to work like this for a while and hope that I dont get any errors